# Docker as a builder, can't install systemd header files

Tags: build, docker, systemd

I'm trying to update a Docker image based on the official CentOS7 image. It is used as a builder for Node.js projects.

I need to add the `systemd-devel` package for compiling some dependencies, but this fails with the following error:

`fakesystemd-1-17.el7.centos.noarch has installed conflicts systemd: fakesystemd-1-17.el7.centos.noarch`

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fakesystemd` is a special package in the CentOS Docker image that satisfies the dependency to Systemd without actually installing Systemd (after all, you don't usually need an init system within a container). `yum info fakesystemd` tells a bit more:

> Minimal docker-specific package to satisfy systemd `Provides:` without installing systemd in Docker images. It is intended strictly for use in Docker images/containers. It doesn't provide any functionality from systemd package - it only contains few important directories and files. fakesystemd is definitely not applicable for full bootable operation system!
>
> To install the real systemd in the image you need to run yum swap command in this form:
>
> ```
> yum swap -- remove fakesystemd -- install systemd systemd-libs
> ```

You need to swap the `fakesystemd` package with the "real" `systemd` package, and can then also install `systemd-devel`:

```
RUN yum swap -y fakesystemd systemd && \
    yum install -y systemd-devel
```