# Docker 's Error: libselinux conflicts with fakesystemd

Tags: docker, centos, dockerfile

I'm building docker image with a Dockerfile:

```
FROM       centos:centos7.1.1503
MAINTAINER foo <foo@bar.com>

ENV TZ "Asia/Shanghai"
ENV TERM xterm

RUN \
    yum update -y && \
    yum install -y epel-release &&\
    yum update -y && \
    yum install -y curl wget tar bzip2 unzip vim-enhanced passwd sudo yum-utils hostname net-tools rsync man && \
    yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ git make automake cmake patch logrotate python-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel && \
    yum install -y pwgen python-pip && \
    yum clean all
```

and it show the error as below:

```
Error: libselinux conflicts with fakesystemd-1-17.el7.centos.noarch
```

If I change `FROM centos:centos7.1.1503` to `FROM centos:centos7`,all will  work fine. So ,what should I do to using **centos7.1.1503**

My Linux Distribution is *Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS* and my docker version is *1.12.6*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36632668/500207 has a solution: replace fakesystemd with a real systemd with `yum swap -- remove fakesystemd -- install systemd systemd-libs`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this inside the container you create, before any installation is made:

```
yum swap -y fakesystemd systemd && yum clean all
yum update -y  && yum clean all
```

Or inside a Dockerfile at the begining before the first RUN you have tipped:

```
RUN yum swap -y fakesystemd systemd && yum clean all \
    && yum update -y  && yum clean all
```

Hope was useful!